# http://deployr.revolutionanalytics.com in not accessible

Tags: r, sql-server-2016, deployr, microsoft-r

I am currently trying out DeployR Open installation based on the documentation available at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/deployr-installing-configuring.

I am however now facing in issue where I cannot access the http://deployr.revolutionanalytics.com website to download the **DeployR-Open-8.0.0.exe**.

Would anyone have an idea how I can get access to the DeployR Open exe?

Comment: where does that first link tell you you need "DeployR-Open-8.0.0.exe"?

Comment: Under the heading **Basic DeployR Install for Windows** point number 2 states **Download and launch the DeployR installer files.**. The second bullet under states I need to download **DeployR-Open-8.0.0.exe**.